# Why are function template specializations distinct, despite no difference in return type or parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Why does the following code work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <class D>
void whichD() {
    std::cout << "D is " << sizeof(D) << " byte(s)\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argv[1][0] == '1') {
        whichD<uint8_t>();
    }
    else {
        whichD<uint16_t>();
    }
}
```

---

###### Program Output for `./temp 1 && ./temp 2`

```
D is 1 byte(s)
D is 2 byte(s)
```

---

I did not expect it to work, for the same reason that you can't have:

```cpp
void foo() { /* ... */ } 
void foo() { /* ... */ } // error: re-definition

int bar() { /* ... */ }
double bar() { /* ... */ } // error: re-definition
```

Comment: Because if the template parameter is specified, the compiler knows what template to instantiate and call. In more fancy terms: because `foo` is a function but `whichD` is a function-template. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU

Comment: Thank you @alfC. But all code needs to eventually boil down to fully specified types, right? At some point, the compiler needs to operate on fully defined code. I've written lots of invalid code over the years trying to write functions with templated return types only (i.e. without unique function parameters) - only to learn that you can't do this. So.. I must have missed a subtlety along the way. I suspect it has something to do with translation units.

Comment: @alfC and I'll watch the link. Thanks for that.

Comment: `whichD<uint8_t>` and `whichD<uint16_t>` are two distinct (and fully specified) types.  Or prehaps it might be better to say, two distinct functions with two different names.  Once you provide the template parameter, you get a concrete type.

Comment: That's right, `foo` is a function, `whichD` is a function-template, while `whichD<int8>` and `whichD<int16>` are back to being functions that the compiler generates. They probably can become concrete code symbols (call them `whichD_int8` and `whichD_int16`). Since these two functions can be syntactically distinguished, the compiler has no problem allowing it. That is the power of templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that functions have to have a different *signature*.
Otherwise, they are re-definitions of each other.
However, what constitutes the *signature* depends on the kind of entity.

#### Signatures of Non-Template Functions

For non-template functions, the signature is defined as:

> ###### signature
>
> ⟨function⟩ name, *parameter-type-list*, and enclosing namespace

- [[defns.signature]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature)

For example:

- `void foo()` and `void bar()` have a different signature, because they have a different name
- `void foo(int)` and `void foo(float)` have a different *parameter-type-list*
- `void a::foo()` and `void b::foo()` have a different enclosing namespace
- `void foo()` and `int foo()` are re-definitions of each other; the return type is not part of the signature, so these functions aren't distinct.

#### Signatures of Function Template Specializations

A function template (e.g. `whichD`) with given template arguments (e.g. `whichD<uint8_t>`) is called a *function template specialization*.
The signature of a *function template specialization* is:

> ###### signature
>
> ⟨function template specialization⟩ signature of the template of which it is a specialization and its template arguments (whether explicitly specified or deduced)

- [[defns.signature.templ.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.signature.spec)

In your example, `whichD<uint8_t>` and `whichD<uint16_t>` are specializations of the same function template but their template arguments are different, making them distinct functions.

The compiler doesn't just drop all the templatey-ness and use the template to produce:

```cpp
void whichD() { /* ... */ }
void whichD() { /* ... */ } // error: re-definition
```

Instead, the compiler will instantiate these specializations, arguments included, and produce something like:

```cpp
void whichD<uint8_t>() { /* ... */ }
void whichD<uint16_t>() { /* ... */ } // OK, different from above
```

The signatures of these two specializations would get *mangled*, so `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are included (in some mangled form) in the symbol that the linker sees.

#### Reason Behind these Rules

Keep in mind that these rules exist to distinguish cases where it's possible to call functions separately, and where it isn't. If `whichD<uint8_t>` and `whichD<uint16_>` weren't specializations, but regular functions with the name `whichD`, you would be unable to call one of the two.
Overload resolution wouldn't be able to distinguish them.

However, as you have demonstrated in your code, it is easily possible to call `whichD<uint8_t>` and `whichD<uint16_t>` separately by providing the template arguments explicitly.
It would be an arbitrary restriction to say that these two have the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler differentiates based on the template parameters.

In your example with `foo`, the compiler cannot deduce which function overload was being called if you call `foo()`, so it throws an error.

Here, `whichD<uint8_t>` and `whichD<uint16_t>` are the same function with different template parameters. Sometime during compilation, these function calls will get transformed to symbols (e.g. `whichD_uint8_t` and `whichD_uint16_t` respectively, or something like that). `whichD_uint8_t` and `whichD_uint16_t` are two different function names, so there is no ambiguity there.